# Join two data sets with two ID cols with missing data in R

Tags: r, missing-data, record-linkage

I need to join two `data.frame`s in `R`, and both of them have two id candidates, but lots of missing data (so I can't just pick one and filter out the rest).

**EDIT** reproducible example of both datasets, and desired outcome:

```
messy1 <- data.frame(id1 = c(11, NA, 13, 11, 12, NA), id2 = c(NA, 22, 23, 21, NA, 23), time = rep(1:2, each = 3))
messy2 <- data.frame(id1 = c(12, NA, 14, 14), id2 = c(22, 23, 24, NA), time = c(1, 1, 1, 2))
desired1 <- data.frame(id1 = rep(11:13, 2), id2 = rep(21:23, 2), time = rep(1:2, each = 3)) # 12/22 is only available in messy2
desired2 <- data.frame(id1 = c(12:13, 14, 14), id2 = c(22:23, 24, 24), time = c(rep(1, 3), 2)) # 13/23 is only available in messy1

desired_joined <- full_join(desired1, desired2)

> messy1
  id1 id2 time
1  11  NA    1
2  NA  22    1
3  13  23    1
4  11  21    2
5  12  NA    2
6  NA  23    2
> messy2
  id1 id2 time
1  12  22    1
2  NA  23    1
3  14  24    1
4  14  NA    2
> desired_joined
  id1 id2 time
1  11  21    1
2  12  22    1
3  13  23    1
4  11  21    2
5  12  22    2
6  13  23    2
7  14  24    1
8  14  24    2
```

**FINAL EDIT**

the example above now accurately reflects the problem I was trying to solve. After figuring this out, the comment provided by @Ben is the actual solution.

Obsolete chunks of the question have been removed to avoind further confusing anyone that bumps into this in the future.

Comment: Consider using `fill` from `tidyr` - you can `group_by` `id1` and `fill` on `id2` (and vice versa).

Comment: That's a good start, thanks! I still can't manage to reproduce the goal above with this approach. I'll edit my current attempt to see where I might be off.

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in my latest edit to the question, the solution is to do a `fill()`. What I found, in the actual RWD is that it's better to do a double-fill with `id1` and `id2`, in each of the datasets before joining. Anyone who needs to do something similar may use the following steps:

```
fill1 <- messy1 %>%
  group_by(id1) %>% fill(id2, .direction = "downup") %>%
  group_by(id2) %>% fill(id1, .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup()

fill2 <- messy2 %>%
  group_by(id1) %>% fill(id2, .direction = "downup") %>%
  group_by(id2) %>% fill(id1, .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup()

full_join(messy1, messy2) %>%
  group_by(id1) %>% fill(id2, .direction = "downup") %>%
  group_by(id2) %>% fill(id1, .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct()

Joining, by = c("id1", "id2", "time")
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   id2 [4]
    id1   id2  time
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    11    21     1
2    12    22     1
3    13    23     1
4    11    21     2
5    12    22     2
6    13    23     2
7    14    24     1
8    14    24     2
```

Note: My actual datasets have ~ 65k rows each, but if I `join` before the `fill` I end up with 2.5M rows (the reason eludes me). By doing all these `fill`s I end up with a much more reasonable 73k rows.