# In R, left join two tables whose 2 potential keys contain missing data

Tags: r, join, dplyr

**Background:**

I'm working with a fairly large (>10,000 rows) dataset of individual cars, and I need to do some analysis on it. I need to keep this dataset `d` intact, but I'm only going to be analyzing cars made by Japanese companies (e.g. Nissan, Honda, etc.). `d` contains information like `VIN_prefix` (the first two letters of a VIN number that indicates the "World Manufacturer Number"), model year, and make, but no explicit indicator of whether the car is made by a Japanese firm. Here's `d`:

```
d <- data.frame(
  make = c("GMC","Dodge","NA","Subaru","Nissan","Chrysler"), 
  model_yr = c("1999","2004","1989","1999","2006","2012"), 
  VIN_prefix = c("1G","1D","JH","JF","NA","2C"),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Here, rows 3, 4, and 5 correspond to Japanese cars: the `NA` in row 3 is actually an Acura whose make is missing. See below when I get to the other dataset about why this is.

`d` also lacks some attributes (columns) about cars that I need for my analysis, e.g. the current CEO of Japanese car firms.

Enter another dataset, `a`, a dataset about Japanese car firms which contains those extra attributes as well as columns that could be used to identify whether a given car (row) in `d` is made by a Japanese firm. One of those is `VIN_prefix`; the other is `jp_makes`, a list of Japanese auto firms. Here's `a`:

```
a <- data.frame(
  VIN_prefix = c("JH","JF","1N"), 
  jp_makes = c("Acura","Subaru","Nissan"),
  current_ceo = c("Toshihiro Mibe","Tomomi Nakamura","Makoto Ushida"), 
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Here, we can see that the "Acura" make, missing in the car from row 3 in `d`, could be identified by its `VIN_prefix` "JH", which in row 3 of `d` is not `NA`.

**Goal:**

Left join `a` onto `d` so that each of the 3 Japanese cars in `d` gets the relevant corresponding attributes from `a` - mainly, `current_ceo`. (Non-Japanese cars in `d` would have `NA` for columns joined from `a`; this is fine.)

**Problem:**

As you can tell, the two relevant variables in `d` that could be used as keys in a join - `make` and `VIN_prefix` - have missing data in `d`. The "matching rules" we could use are imperfect: I could match on `d$make == a$jp_makes` or on `d$VIN_prefix == a$VIN_prefix`, but they'd each be wrong due to the missing data in `d`.

What to do?

**What I've tried:**

I can try left joining on either one of these potential keys, but not all 3 of the Japanese cars in `d` wind up with their correct information from `a`:

```
try1 <- left_join(d, a, by = c("make" = "jp_makes"))

try2 <- left_join(d, a, by = c("VIN_prefix" = "VIN_prefix"))
```

I can successfully generate an logical 'indicator' variable in `d` that tells me whether a car is Japanese or not:

```
entries_make <- a$jp_makes
entries_vin_prefix <- a$VIN_prefix

d<- d %>%
  mutate(is_jp = ifelse(d$VIN_prefix %in% entries_vin_prefix | d$make %in% entries_make, 1, 0) 
         %>% as.logical())
```

But that only gets me halfway: I still need those other columns from `a` to sit next to those Japanese cars in `d`. It's unfeasible to manually fill all the missing data in some other way; the real datasets these toy examples correspond to are too big for that and I don't have the manpower or time.

Ideally, I'd like a dataset that looks something like this:

```
ideal <- data.frame(
  make = c("GMC","Dodge","NA","Subaru","Nissan","Chrysler"), 
  model_yr = c("1999","2004","1989","1999","2006","2012"), 
  VIN_prefix = c("1G","1D","JH","JF","NA","2C"),
  current_ceo = c("NA", "NA", "Toshihiro Mibe","Tomomi Nakamura","Makoto Ushida", "NA"),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

What do you all think? I've looked at other posts (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67458783/join-two-data-sets-with-two-id-cols-with-missing-data-in-r)) but their solutions don't really apply. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The problem with your description is that there are not 3 Japanese makes in `d`. You are not saying what matching or alignment rule is to be used when the make is `NA` or "NA".

Comment: I've edited the post to clarify. There are indeed 3 Japanese makes in `d`: rows 3, 4, and 5. Row 3 can only be shown to be Japanese by its VIN_prefix, but it's indeed an Acura. Let me know if my edits make more sense, and thanks for the feedback.

Comment: That was very helpful in advancing my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left join on an OR of the two conditions.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select d.*, a.current_ceo
  from d
  left join a on d.VIN_prefix = a.VIN_prefix or d.make = a.jp_makes")
```

giving:

```
      make model_yr VIN_prefix     current_ceo
1      GMC     1999         1G            <NA>
2    Dodge     2004         1D            <NA>
3       NA     1989         JH  Toshihiro Mibe
4   Subaru     1999         JF Tomomi Nakamura
5   Nissan     2006         NA   Makoto Ushida
6 Chrysler     2012         2C            <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It seems to be working on my real datasets, where `d` = ~150,000 rows and `a` = ~1000 -- but fairly slowly, and I have a very capable machine. I don't mean to sound ungrateful, but is there a way to speed sqldf up, that you know about?

Comment: Using an OR in sql is generally slow but you could try adding indexes, e.g. `sqldf(c("create index i1 on d(VIN_prefix)", "create index i2 on d(make)", 
  "select d.*, a.current_ceo 
   from d left join a on d.VIN_prefix = a.VIN_prefix or d.make = a.jp_makes"))`
or alternately try indexing on a.  `sqldf(c("create index i1 on a(VIN_prefix)", "create index i2 on a(jp_makes)", 
  "select d.*, a.current_ceo 
   from d left join a on d.VIN_prefix = a.VIN_prefix or d.make = a.jp_makes"))` Try it on a subset first.  The indexing will take time but may save more than it adds.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try indexing and see if it helps. Last question for you: could joining on an "or", as you suggested here, cause the dataframe resulting from the left join to have a larger number of rows than the original? It seems that some extra rows are exact duplicates of Japanese cars, but not all. Any insight? If `d` originally has 6 observations, I'd like the result of joining `d` to `a` to have 6 too. In the example, this happens, but not in my real data. Understand if this is beyond your capacity to answer here. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Yes, if there are multiple matches.  If the multiple matches result in rows that are identical in every column and you only want one then use `select distinct ...` instead of `select`.   If you just want an arbitrary row from the rows that match a particular d row then add `group by d.rowid` to the end of the select statement.

Comment: In thinking about this some more I think you want to index the a data frame rather than the d data frame since it is going to have to do a complete scan of d anyways but you can try them both on a subset just in case to get some insight.

Answer (score 1):

Use a two pass method. First fill in the missing make (or VIN values). I'll illustrate  by filling in `make` valuesDo notice taht "NA" is not the same as `NA`. The first is a character value while the latter is a true R missing value, so I'd first convert those to a true missing value. In natural language I am replacing the missing values in  `d` (note correction of `df`) with values of 'jp_makes' that are taken from `a` on the basis of matching VIN_prefix values:

```
 is.na( d$make) <- df$make=="NA"
 d$make[is.na(df$make)] <- a$jp_makes[
                              match( d$VIN_prefix[is.na(d$make)], a$VIN_prefix) ]
```

Now you have the `make` values filled in on the basis of the table look up in `a`. It should be trivial to do the match you wanted by using `by.x='make', by.y='jp_make'`

```
 merge(d, a, by.x='make', by.y='jp_makes', all.x=TRUE)
      make model_yr VIN_prefix.x VIN_prefix.y     current_ceo
1    Acura     1989           JH           JH  Toshihiro Mibe
2 Chrysler     2012           2C         <NA>            <NA>
3    Dodge     2004           1D         <NA>            <NA>
4      GMC     1999           1G         <NA>            <NA>
5   Nissan     2006           NA           1N   Makoto Ushida
6   Subaru     1999           JF           JF Tomomi Nakamura
```

You can then use the values in `VIN_prefix.y` to replace the values the `=="NA"` in `VIN_prefix.x`.

Comment: Yes I did mean "true" R `NA` values, not the chars I put in the post. I'm going to try and adapt your solution to my "real" datasets right now. Thanks a million. Will report back.

Comment: Getting a couple of errors: `Error in df$make : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` . When you say df$make, did you mean d$make? I don't have a dataset `df` in my example ;-)

Comment: My original had `df` in a couple of places that should have been `d`. The weird error message arises because`df` is a function name (density of the F-distribution) and the interpreter could not find a df data-object (as you said).